# Multiple source power supply

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, voltage-regulator

I am trying to design a micro-controller power supply that can use three power sources with a particular order of priority. The sources are:

1. 5V USB - overrides all other sources when available
2. 12V DC - only on when micro-controller provides a 3.3V enable.
3. 3.7V LiIon battery - charged from the other two when available

The current requirements of this system are less than 100mA @ 3.3V.

My concept, shown in the schematic, is to use power a 3.3V LDO regulator from 5V (if present) or the battery. The battery has a charge controller that is powered by 5V (this charging circuit is described in [Microchip AN1149](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01149c.pdf)). The 5V can come from either USB or from another 12V rail via a buck regulator. The USB 5V must supersede the 12V supply and the microcontroller can also turn off the 12V source. I would like the buck regulator to power off when 12V source is not used.

I have attached a sketch of my circuit concept but I am unsure about the correct use of MOSFETs and Schottky diodes in this context. With the voltage regulators and charge controller in the system I am not sure how to simulate this.

Can anyone help me determine if this MOSFET configuration makes sense and what I need to do to bias them correctly for each operating state?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Please use reference designators for the components. Then it is easier to say: *The PMOS that has a gate resistor of 10k* will always conduct: either by being turned on or by its body diode.

Comment: There is quite some more to say about the circuit, but it's easier if you use reference designators (i.e. 'number' the components, mosfets as M1, M2, etc and diodes as D1, D2, etc)

Comment: Sorry, added the designators. Good point.

Comment: If you want 12V on the input of U1, you need 12V on the source of Q2. If you drive the gate with 3.3 V, Vgs would be 3.3-12= -8.7V. But that Vgs never turns on a NMOS.

Comment: Note that USB isn't exactly 5.0V, but can be +/-10%. So, when USB is present, but only with 4.5V, the 12V to 5V DC/DC converter will still supersede.

Comment: The purpose of Q1 is the ensure that the USB voltage cuts off the 12V sourced branch regardless.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem with Q2's Vgs but I don't know how to adjust the design to fix this. Maybe I need to drive a common-source MOSFET with the 3.3V logic to pull down 12V on the Q2 gate. I am also concerned about the effects of the MOSFET body diodes.

Comment: I would like to play around with this in spice but I need a simple model to represent the switching regulator and the 5V load of the bottom half of the circuit.

Comment: You may find it easier to use integrated circuits than these discrete parts. Look for “power control”, or “power switches “  at the semiconductor web sites or Digi-Key.

Comment: @user69795 Thanks for the tip. I think I am on to something with  "high-side load switches" or "high-side driver".  Maybe there are better search keywords for the kind of power distribution scheme I am looking for?

Comment: Those are the words to search on. It applies to Q1, Q2 and Q3